# How to make one color attribute for 2 separate objects?

Tags: color, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I have 2 objects that I cannot connect to a common mesh, but at the same time I need to paint them together. Can I do this?
[image: Text]

Comment: It might be easier to paint a common texture both meshes share.

Comment: @scurest it might be easier, but I need a solution for just such a task. So I can paint 2 or more objects at once

Answer (score 1):

You can only vertex paint one object at a time. You can join multiple meshes together to one object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, paint them as one object, then separate them (<kbd>P</kbd> in edit mode) and they will each keep the vertex paint. If you have complex objects consisting of many separate mesh parts making them inconvenient to select if joined, you could create vertex groups and assign all single object's geometry to different group for each of your objects so they are easy to select and separate later.